# File Upload in Django Form to Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Say I have a form with a multi-file upload field. 
How would I properly use the `for` loop to iterate over each file that was uploaded? I've only gotten as far as verifying that it did indeed catch multiple files (for example, sending an email for each file uploaded results in me getting 2 emails). My end goal is to save them to a model.

```
#views.py
def contact(request):
    foo = RequestForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if foo.is_valid():
        saved_attachments = request.FILES.getlist('tag')
        for a_file in saved_attachments:
            ## grab first file
            a_file.save()
```

Comment: If you are to save them to a model, simply create instances of the model in your loop; then save them.

Comment: I see where you are going with this, but it will only take the 1st uploaded file. Looking at it logically, everything listed in the loop it will do it twice. I make an instance, I assign it to the image (the 1st image), then I save it. The loop starts over, but grabs the 1st image again..